# Why does Command-N not open a new window in Safari? It opens a new Tab instead

Tags: safari, tabs, window, macos-big-sur

I want to open a new window in Safari.  The stated File menu shortcut for this in the Safari app is Command-N. When I type Command-N "New Window" in Safari on Big Sur, I get a new tab.  There is no key combination that results in a new window except command-shift-N, which I don't want to use as it makes a private browser window.
Safari settings has "Open pages in tabs instead of new windows" set to "Never."  So that's not the problem...  any ideas?  Does this work for anyone besides me?
Thanks

Comment: I completely reinstalled Big Sur and the problem went away.  So I'll never know what caused this.

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution!

Go into System Preferences, General (settings).
Toward the bottom there is a setting for "Prefer Tabs" with a dropdown menu. Change it to "in full screen".

Fixed it for me.